# ForeignObject not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, safari, mobile-safari

I am using d3.js for a simple data visualization. It is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.
ForeignObject is showing odd behavior on Safari Mac browser. The text is shifted towards left (picture attached). This problem was related to positioning of the two divs. I removed **position: absolute** on **#innerDiv** and **position: relative** on parent div. This solved the problem. But, I am not able to vertically center the text (which was the purpose of the above thing).

On IOS Safari (mobile version), it doesn't even display anything (picture attached)

What is the visualization about?
It shows the life events of scientists. When you hover over a colored section of grid, it shows the corresponding information in the right box.
Following is the part of code which displays the foreignObject.

```
      /* MAKE COMPLETE MODAL BOX HERE */
      var modalBox = d3.select("#mainSVG")
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("id", "modalBOXgroup")
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("id", "modalBOX")
                     .attr("x", "600")
                     .attr("y", "45")
                     .attr("rx", "20")
                     .attr("rx", "20")
                     .attr("width", "580")
                     .attr("height", getSVGheight() - 60)
                     .style("fill", singleDayEvents[0].color)
                     .style("stroke", "white")
                     .style("stroke-width", "5px");

      var modalTitle = d3.select("#modalBOXgroup")
                               .append("foreignObject")
                               .attr("x", "620")
                               .attr("y", "70")
                               .attr("width", "540")
                               .attr("height", getSVGheight() - 110)
                               .append("xhtml:div")
                               .style("height", "100%")
                               .style("color", "white")
                               .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                               .style("position", "relative")
                               .append("xhtml:div")
                               .attr("id", "innerDiv")
                               .style("position", "absolute")
                               .style("top", "50%")
                               .style("width", "100%")
                               .style("transform", "translateY(-50%)")
                               .style("overflow", "auto")
                               .append("h3")
                               .attr("id", "modalTitle")
                               .style("color", "white")
                               .style("text-align", "center")
                               .style("text-decoration", "underline")
                               .text(singleDayEvents[0].title);

      var modalDescription = d3.select("#modalBOXgroup foreignObject #innerDiv")
                               .append("p")
                               .attr("id", "modalDescription")
                               .style("font-size", "14px")
                               .style("text-align", "justify")
                               .style("line-height", "30px")
                               .text(singleDayEvents[0].desc);

      /* MAKE COMPLETE MODAL BOX HERE */
```

You can visit this link to check it out:
https://conductscience.com/age-when-charles-darwin/

**PS** I have tried adding namespace (with xmlns attribute) to both divs inside foreignObject. But it didn't work.

Pictures:
[Safari Mac Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GoeU.jpg)[Safari IOS Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQT22.png)

Comment: @RobertLongson Odd behaviour was that the text was shifted towards left. I have edited the question to include the image.